# set zindex for map objects in here maps android

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I am trying to setzindex of some map objects in here maps using here maps premium android sdk.
My problem is I have set navigation route and along those route I want to show truck restrictions.
I tried changing setzindex of the maproute object but truck restrictions along the route is still hiding.

This is what my code snippet looks like.

```
@Override
public void onCalculateRouteFinished(@NonNull List<RouteResult> routeResults, @NonNull RoutingError routingError) {
  if (routingError == RoutingError.NONE) {
     if (routeResults.get(0).getRoute() != null) {
        route = routeResults.get(0).getRoute();
        mapRoute = new MapRoute(route);
        mapRoute.setZIndex(0);
        map.addMapObject(mapRoute);
                    
        map.setFleetFeaturesVisible(EnumSet.of(Map.FleetFeature.TRUCK_RESTRICTIONS)); //*not showing along route
                 .........          
       } 
    } 
 }
```

How can put truck restrictions above map route in android?

Comment: set different zIndex to restriction objects

Comment: @NDroidev Setting z index of other objects in map works but cannot set Z index of truck restrictions. In any case, need to show truck restrictions above/along the route. I am not able to achieve this.